# Call to undefined method Mage_Directory_Helper_Data::getRegionJsonByStore() in admin sales order create

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, sales-order, admin-order-create

This is very strange. I disabled both app/community and app/local as well as replaced app/core with stock Magento files and yet I keep getting the following error:

> Call to undefined method `Mage_Directory_Helper_Data::getRegionJsonByStore()` in /var/www/site-root/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Renderer/Region.php on line 87

Not sure how to troubleshoot from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Mage_Directory_Helper_Data::getRegionJsonByStore()` was introduced in Magento 1.8, so it sounds like your Mage_Directory_Helper_Data class is from an older version.

The most likely explanation is an override in `app/code/local`. You did not explain how you "disabled app/local" but it probably didn't work.

Comment: thanks for your response. What I had tried prior to submitting the question was disabling the module in a quick and hacky way - renaming them so that they weren't found, disabled all cache and then I would clear the cache that Mag always produces. I *thought* I'd repeated this same process when I disabled this directory but I must have failed to clear the cache or refreshed before the file had been changed on the server.

In short, disabling the `./app/code/local/Mage/Directory` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check `Configuration -> System -> Tools -> Compilation`, it should be disabled. If not, disable it.

If it does not fix your problem, then try to replace the file `app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Helper\Data.php` with the original copy, backup your copy of course just in case.

Answer (score 1):

How to troubleshoot missing methods:

1. If compilation is enabled, recompile and flush cache.
2. Disable APC if enabled.
3. Enable [opcache timestamps](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps) if disabled
4. Enable Xdebug, set a breakpoint in Mage::getModel() and trace what file it resolves to. If that file is outside your document root, verify include_path.
5. If 4. resolves to the correct file, but you're still getting the errors, restart php interpreter (php-fpm or Apache).
6. If 5 fixed it, but 2&3 didn't, verify if there are other opcode caches enabled and tune them.
7. If 5 fixed it but you are not aware of any opcode caches, contact your hoster for information and diagnosis.

If none of the above worked, verify you are on the right server.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Directory_Helper_Data::getRegionJsonByStore()` doesn't exist up to Magento CE 1.7.0.2. This method appeared in 1.8+.

It's look like an upgrade result . Do you upgrade mage extension through Magento Connect in admin?

If yes, you need upgrade all Magento Core modules. But upgrade by magento connect will skip `lib/*` folder. Try upgrade `lib/*` folder manually.

The other possible solution is to refresh/disable your cache under Admin-> System -> Cache Management. And don't forget to click "Flush Magento Cache" button.